# MQTTbox adds random number to clientid

Tags: mqtt

While using MQTTBox, I saw that whenever Im putting custom MQTT Client Id, it add a random number to the end of it.
For example, clientId named testing became testing1513857051789
.

I'm doing the tests for AWS IoT env (if thats important). While trying to do the tests with mosquitto client it works perfectly.

Comment: There isn't actually a question here, just a statement. I assume you are wanting to know how to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that 'Append timestamp to MQTT client id?' option was marked.